# Full screen Dialog puts grey color on status bar and navigation bar Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I made a full screen dialog using Jetpack compose but every time i try to change status bar and navigation bar color, i get a strong gray overlay that makes every color i chose, almost dark grey.

I've already tried to set custom style in styles.xml file and used the systemUi controller to change colors with the following code:

```
    val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController().apply {
        setNavigationBarColor(navigationBarColor)
        setStatusBarColor(statusBarColor)
    }
```

Nothing really worked. What can i do?

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65243956/jetpack-compose-fullscreen-dialog

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, and have find the solution:

By default statusBar has a layer with 30% opaque black color even if color has been set to transparent.

```
private val BlackScrim = Color(0f, 0f, 0f, 0.3f) // 30% opaque black
private val BlackScrimmed: (Color) -> Color = { original ->
BlackScrim.compositeOver(original)
}
```

It the setNavigationBarColor you need to change transformColorForLightContent.

Set Transperent color or another if needed instead black.

```
private val noScrimmed: (Color) -> Color = { original ->
Color.Transperent.compositeOver(original)
}
setNavigationBarColor( transformColorForLightContent = noScrimmed)
```

Comment: Doesn't work in latest Jetpack Compose Material 3